# How to only allow a specific machine to run a task in Luigi

Tags: python, luigi

`Machine A` has the ability to access a SQL database and `Machine B` has the ability to access Google Drive. How do I make sure that a task is run on the correct machine if `UploadToDrive` depends on `DownloadSQLData` somewhere down the line?

Currently `Machine A` runs `DoSomethingElseWithData` and `Machine B` runs `UploadToDrive` a few minutes later. This is fine up until the point where one day `Machine A` might not be working, at which point `Machine B` will attempt `DownloadSQLData` as an upstream dependency and fail.

```py
class DownloadSQLData(luigi.Task):

    # ...

    def run(self):
        # Only Machine A can do this
        # ...

class TransformData(luigi.Task):

    # ...

    def requires(self):
        return DownloadSQLData(date=self.date)

class UploadToDrive(luigi.Task):

    # ...

    def requires(self):
        return TransformData(date=self.date)

    def run(self):
        # Only Machine B can do this
        # ...

class DoSomethingElseWithData(luigi.Task):

    #...

    def requires(self):
        return TransformData(date=self.date)
```

The SQL database from this example is, in reality, not a SQL database but an old system within our company. It does not fail gracefully when unauthorised users try to access it and we'd like to avoid any attempts from `Machine B` to do so.

Comment: When you say points to, do you mean runs? So machine `A` runs `DoSomethingElseWithData` and machine `B` runs `UploadToDrive`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Edited to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luigi itself cannot do scheduling, i.e., running certain tasks on certain machines or scheduling tasks to run at a certain time. That being said, there are many ways to achieve what you want.

**Solution 1:** Let's introduce machine `C` that has access to machines `A` and `B`. Using a number of tools (https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell) machine `C` could run tasks to retrieve data from `A`, transform it on `C`, and then transfer to `B` before uploading.

**Solution 2:** *This solution is most likely too much work and/or infeasible.* Set up machines `A,B,C` in a network scheduler (something like slurm https://www.schedmd.com/) with `C` as the head scheduler and specify `A` and `B` as certain types of resources (possibly `SQL` and `GDrive`). Then, from `C`, schedule slurm tasks as luigi jobs (https://github.com/pharmbio/sciluigi can help with this). These slurm tasks should specify the given resources needed for each task. And that's **it**!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not surprised it's not directly doable within Luigi. Unfortunately all our machines are Windows 7 so ssh is a little more tricky. I'm actually considering adding an external task `TransformedData` that has the same output path as `TransformData` and have that be a requirement for `UploadToDrive` instead, and use the `--keep-alive` flag on `B`. It feels a little hacky to me, but the Google Drive section is a short term requirement anyway, and I won't have to spend time fiddling with communication between the machines.

Comment: It all sounds a bit hacky to me. Haha. Also, if you are satisfied with the answer, consider marking it ask correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [luigi.task.externalize](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/luigi.task.html#luigi.task.externalize) to create different stacks of tasks to be run on different machines:

- Machine A:

  - DownloadSQLData
  - externalize(DownloadSQLData) -> TransformData -> DoSomethingElseWithData
- Machine B:

  - externalize(TransformData) -> UploadToDrive
  - externalize(DownloadSQLData) -> TransformData -> DoSomethingElseWithData